# Stop qt application in infinite loop when main window is closed

Tags: c++, qt, infinite-loop

My main application class is `USB_Packet_Analyzer` which processes some files, but also supports reading from a file to which somebody still writes. In that case, I have an infinity loop which checks whether something new was written in this file and if so, I continue in processing. In every iteration of loop I am calling `QCoreApplication::processEvents();`.
The problem is that when I close main window of app, it wont stop the application. If I check `QApplication::topLevelWidgets().size()` it is still 1, and `QApplication::topLevelWidgets().at(0)->isVisible()` is false. Why isn't it closing my window? Can I connect some signal to detect whether red cross on window was clicked or not? I know that when getting into this kind of loops i might use `QThread`, but I'd rather not get this involved. Is there any solution for my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [QFileSystemWatcher](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemwatcher.html) Class and its [fileChanged](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemwatcher.html#fileChanged) signal.

```
#include <QFileSystemWatcher>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);

private:
    QFileSystemWatcher* fileWatcher;
    Ui::MainWindow*ui;
};

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    createUi();
            
    fileWatcher = new QFileSystemWatcher(this);
    connect(fileWatcher, SIGNAL(fileChanged(QString)), this, SLOT(fileChangedSlot(QString)));
            
    QFileInfo file("file_to_watch.txt");
        
    if (file.exists())
    {
        fileWatcher->addPath(file.absoluteFilePath());
    }
}
        
void MainWindow::fileChangedSlot(const QString &path)
{
    if (fileWatcher->files().contains(path))
    {
        qDebug() << "File changed" << path;
    }
}
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: I think this is the right way to solve this, but I have problem that `fileChangedSlot` is called only after i minimize my main window whose class implements given slot. Any idea why ?

Answer (score 1):

in my main loop i check if the window is open. If it closes, I terminate the program.

```
  if (my_windows.isActiveWindow()) == False:
        sys.exit(my_app.exec())
        break
```

Everything about my application in task manager has been terminated.
I don't have a problem at the moment but I'm open to better suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can using of system interrupt signal to manage a Boolean to breaking your infinite loop or exiting the application.

e.g:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <csignal>

using namespace std;

void InterruptSignalHandler(int signal_number) {
    cout<< "Signal Number is "<<signal_number<<endl;
    exit(signal_number);
}

int main()
{
    signal(SIGINT, InterruptSignalHandler);
    string a;
    while(true)
    {
        cout<<">";
        cin >> a;
    }

    return 0;
}
```